# Nesting ng-repeat on one element for filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a page which is built up of tiles (imagine a list of div's with a thumbnail and a title) - each 'tile' can have several tags attributed to them..

E.g:

- tile 1 has the following tags: `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `quz`
- tile 2 has the following tags: `foo`, `bar`, `baz`
- tile 3 has the following tags: `bar`, `baz`
- tile 4 has the following tags: `baz`, `quz`
  .. and so on..

At the top of the page there is a simple filter menu - with each tag clickable in a list.

When clicking a tag in the filter menu e.g. `foo`, hide any tile which hasn't got the `foo` tag attributed to it. In this case, tiles 3 and 4 will be removed from view.

Each tile has the following template, but I need to extend this to incorporate the tag filtering...

```
<div ng-repeat="tile in tiles" class="col-md-2" ng-show="showFiles.filters[tile.filetype]">
  <div class="sc-file-container">
    <h3>{{tile.name}}</h3> // add image here too
  </div>
</div>
```

Very new to the angular way, but basically in order to use ng-hide/ng-show I've been creating arrays in the controller `$scope` - see above, so when showFiles.filters['tile.filetype'] is set true (by an onclick via a directive on another filter menu for example), the tile will show or hide..

Question: As there are potentially several tags attributed to each tile - what would be the best way to utilise `ng-show` in the above example? How can I iterate over the tags array - but keep within the `<div>`? Is it possible to have 2 `ng-repeat`'s on one element or would I have to create several dummy `<div>` wrappers, just to apply for example `ng-show="filterByTag['foo']"` to the tile

Example of json:

```
"tiles" : {
..
.
"filetype" : "pdf",
"name" : "this is tile 1!",
..

 "tags":[  
  {  
    "id":1,
    "name":"foo"
  },
  {  
    "id":2,
    "name":"bar"
  },
  {  
    "id":3,
    "name":"baz"
  }
  ..
 ]
 ..
}
```

Comment: you should implement a directive and render an html Template depending on your filter. You would not have to use ng-repeat since your directive would do the job. If I got more time later I'll try to show an example. Otherwise (easy way), use jQuery [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to do this in angular is filter your tiles array based on selected tag filter.

```
<div ng-repeat="tile in filteredTiles" class="col-md-2">
   <div class="sc-file-container">
      <h3>{{tile.name}}</h3> // add image here too
   </div>
</div>

<script>
     var filteredTiles = [];
     // Logic to filter tiles based on selected tag in filter

</script>
```

Comment: So if the filteredTiles object gets updated - say remove an item from the object (when it gets filtered) should this reflect in ng-repeat?

Comment: Yes when ever you update your scope.filteredTiles object change will be relfected in the view

Comment: Excellent - I can ditch all my ng-show code and just update the object in ng-repeat. Didn't realise I could do that..! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is i would say a bit not correct. There are filters available in the angular to filter out the data but for this you need to update the model `ng-model`. I guess you should do it like this:

#### Markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button id='foo' ng-model='clickedItem.item' ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'click' }" ng-btn>Foo</button>
  <button id='bar' ng-model='clickedItem.item' ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'click' }" ng-btn>Bar</button>
  <button id='baz' ng-model='clickedItem.item' ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'click' }" ng-btn>Baz</button>
  <div ng-repeat="tile in tiles | filter:clickedItem.item" class="col-md-2">
    <div class="sc-file-container">
      <h3>{{tile.name}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

In the above markup you can see that we have three buttons with different ids like `foo, bar, baz` and those buttons also have two directives `ng-model` and `ng-model-options` and below that where you have `ng-repeat` you have to have a filter as you can see in the markup as `ng-repeat="tile in tiles | filter:clickedItem.item"`.

Now whenever model updates you can see the difference. That only happens when you use `ng-model-options="{updateOn:'click'}"` which says update the model whenever `click` happens on the button.

#### angularjs code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { // controller
  $scope.clickedItem = {}; // holds the clicked button's id
  $scope.tiles = [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}, {name: 'baz'}];
}).directive('ngBtn', function(){
  return {
    link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
      angular.element(elem).on('click', function(){ // click on button
        scope.clickedItem.item = this.id; // update clickedItem
      });
    }
  };
});
```

### [See the demo @ plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/GcaiQEY4JNYPk3gZWrAe?p=preview)